# Asp .Net Core Web API

Tags: .net-core

I have developed a .net api application. I want only me to have access to it and no one else. How to make protection in an easy way?

I don't know where to start. I want to do without authorization server I use visual studio 2022

Comment: You can use api-keys and don't give that to someone else!

Comment: This is far too broad a question. You don't even need authentication if you don't expose the API. You can easily use Windows Authentication on IIS to prevent any unauthorized users from calling your API. You can block/whitelist IPs on the server itself. In ASP.NET Core itself, you can use ASP.NET Identity and Basic authentication (username/password) without an extra server. You can combine that with ASP.NET Identity (the middleware, not the authentication server)

Comment: What are the *actual* requirements? The way the question is written, the answer can only be the [entire ASP.NET Core Authentication chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). If you want Basic Authentication, you can create a web API with `Individual` authentication, which stores accounts in a database. If you want to use API keys/tokens, you can use JWTs without another server.

Comment: You can use `.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();` to add JWT autentication and the `user-jwts` tool to generate tokens and store them at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<secrets_GUID>\user-jwts.json`. This is only meant for development, but it may be enough for your scenario. This is explained in [Manage JSON Web Tokens in development with dotnet user-jwts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/jwt-authn?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows)

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't mention how and where would you deploy the application but as a general rule these are the protective measures

### Authentication/Authorization

The most basic authentication is sending a token along with your request, for the most basic one send a token as a parameter and check it in the API controller, BUT for a more practical technique use
Authentication/Authorization token in the header and on of the most used tokens is JWT which you can use it both in front end and back end
You just send the token in the header and use [Authorize] attribute in the controller
even if you want to access the api with apps such as postman or insomnia you will have to add the token to the header.

### How to acquire JWT token

This could be acquired using username/password system in your backend

### Why use JWT token

- A JWT token can contain any additional authorization roles and not only authentication.
- It works in any condition, locally deployed, local network or on the web.

### Definitions

**Authentication:** The case in which you tell that this user is a valid user of the application.
**Authorization:** The case in which you tell which controller or method that this user is allowed to use, and this is done through assigning roles

### Example

In the "startup.cs" file you add authentication and authorization

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["keyjwt"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Bearer");
                defaultAuthorizationBuilder = defaultAuthorizationBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationBuilder.Build();
            });
```

Then in the controller responsible for generating the token make a login endpoint

private readonly SignInManager signInManager;

```
[HttpPost("LogIn")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AuthResponse>> LogIn(User user)
        {

            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, user.PassWord,
                isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return await BuildToken(user);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Error login");
            }
        }
```

And this is the AuthResponse model that is returned containing the token and the expiry

```cs
public class AuthResponse
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    }
```

Don't forget to add the "keyjwt" to appsettings.json something like this

```cs
"keyjwt": "RJDHAT1SYKU4YGJ76ARGAE9DHH3KK7LJTF4DS3AD2SG4GFJJH8LK9JF0DDGD87FGKDHDFGNJDFGHDFHGFGJERTERHETRYTRUYRTYHEJLUJHYS",
```

Then you could add the [Authorize] attribute for endpoints you want to have authorized access

N.B. I didn't add the claims/roles for simplicity

Hope these information are adequate if you have extra questions don't hesitate to ask
Good Day

N.B.: You don't need to implement it using Authorization server, You could simply make everything static a fixed key, fixed token and only you who know it.

Thanks to  Panagiotis Kanavos for valuable comments

Comment: This answer contains no information, no starting points and even contradicts itself when it talk about JWT as if it was Basic Authentication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right it's not the most basic technique, bet may be the most basic acceptable/secure technique, as the question owner said he is a beginner, let's agree that building our career on the right foundation better than depending on non standardized techniques which would lead to get used to it and it would be hard in the future to accept the right techniques

Comment: I said there's no information, not that this isn't the most basic. There are a lot of words. `Basic Authentication` is an actual authentication type, using username and password. This answer will only confuse beginners.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your clarification I'll edit the answer to include it.

Comment: The clarification is that this isn't an answer, just a very verbose and incorrect discussion on "authentication" that contradicts itself. A link to the docs or the ASP.NET Core authentication Quickstart would be  a lot more useful

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your valuable comment I've added code snippets to clarify the answer, thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

You can learn about middlware , use path and client_ID confirm

example :

if(context.Request.Path.Value=="/swagger/index.html?client_id=key")